# When stepping through my program the ToString() method is being called for no reason

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, tostring

This is a bizarre problem I'm having even my senior programmer next to me is also confused. The issue in full is that somehow my `ToString()` method is being called and I don't know or understand how this is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Blank Constructor");
    Form form = new Form(); <-- ToString() gets called on this line.
    form.ToString();

    Console.Read();
 }

public Form()
{
    FormName = "";
    FormImageLocation = "";
    FormDescription = "";

    FormID = 0;

    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;

    Fields = new List<Field>();
    Packets = new List<Packet>(); <-- This line in the constructor
}

public override string ToString()
{
    string returnString;
    returnString = " Form Name: " +  FormName + " Form Image Location: " + FormImageLocation + "Form     Description: " + FormDescription + " FormID: " + FormID  + " Created Date: " + CreatedDate + "           LastUpdate: " + LastUpdate ;

    if (fields.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            returnString += field.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        returnString += "!!! This Form has no Fields !!!";
    }

    if (Packets.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (var packet in Packets)
        {
            returnString += packet.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        returnString += " !!! This Form does not belong to any Packets !!!";
    }

    Console.Out.WriteLine(returnString);
    return returnString;
}

public Packet(string packet_name, List<Form> list_of_forms)
{
    PacketName = packet_name;
    forms = list_of_forms;
}
```

This seemingly random recurrence of the `ToString()` printing ONLY occurs when i step through the program. it will print on the line I designated above and also when the constructor exits and prints like crazy as I'm stepping through the `ToString()` method itself. I placed a break point in the `ToString()` but it will only stop on the breakpoint when the `ToString()` is legitimetly called, so to be clear when i step through and it does this random printing it will not stop at the breakpoints within the `ToString()`. I went through and removed all calls to the `ToString()` and it still get randomly called, when i commented out the `returnString` variable and just returned "her there" the problem went away but that doesn't help anything. if i just run the program without breakpoints this problem does not occur. some of you may say that if it works when running it doesn't matter but it makes me extremely wary that if i run into a code issue down the road and i try to step through the code to find the problem i will get different results and hinder the debugging. I tried cover the whole issue and what i have tried and provide all code needed, if i was unclear about something let me know and i will try to explain it again. lastly I am on a Windows 7 64 bit machine and I am using Visual Studio C# 2010 Express.

Answer (score 7):

You probably have a watch on the form, or are in some other way displaying it's value in the debugger (through the "locals" window, the stack trace, etc.). The debugger uses `ToString` to display objects.  If this is a problem in your program, you should likely re-design your `ToString` such that it *isn't* a problem for it to be called like this, or else simply avoiding using the debugger.

Having a very "expensive" `ToString` that you generally wish to avoid using is a situation to be wary of.  There can be occasional exceptions where it does make sense, but callers generally expect it to be a cheap operation.  Consider whether or not it would be appropriate to have some other method/property representing a display string that is more involved, leaving a simpler/cheaper `ToString` implementation.

Comment: Sounds similar to what happens when you override the OnPaint event of a control and it throws errors in the design view.

Comment: You can also add a `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` to your class, which will be used instead of ToString when the debugger is attached: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Logarr Meh, the debugger handles exceptions here fine; it just says that there was an exception rather than crashing the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

The debugger may call ToString if you watch it or even if you just hover the mouse over the object.
Usually it is a good idea to keep side effects in ToString at a bare minimum. I.e. ToString should not cause any state change.

A similar problem occurs if you watch properties and the get method has side effects.

Another problem is when using LINQ, since the debugger may evaluate the IEnumerable returned from an LINQ expression, which may cause all sort of side effects.
With LINQ it may get even more tricky. If you have some code that actually rely on the LINQ expression being reevaluated (say some code that polls some LINQ expression until some condition is true), then you can gain some gray hairs when debugging, since the debugger may cache the expression and not re-evaluate it as you expect.

Another similar debugging nightmare: Debugging focus events. Very hard to do, since activating the debugger will steal focus and cause side effects. Sometimes good old-fashion print statements are the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in order to display those DateTimes in Form(), the debugger is calling ToString() on them when you try to instantiate a new Form()...  as @Servy has mentioned

Since you are using more than just strings in your Form() class, ToString() has to be called to display the locals in the stop point you've set for debugging and you'll need to use the DebuggerDisplayAttribute accordingly or change the way you're overriding ToString().

[MSDN Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the debugger will call `ToString` to visualize your class in multiple locations. This includes the Autos, Locals and Watch windows. If you don't want the Debugger to call ToString, or want to short-circuit when the debugger is attached you have a few options.

### [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute` or `DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can add one of these two attributes to your Class definition. When running in the debugger it will pick up these attributes and use the alternative method or format string supplied by these attributes instead of your `ToString()` method. The following shows the forms `Title` property instead.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("MyForm under debugger {Title}")]
public class MyForm : Form
{

}
```

### [`Debugger.IsAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can also check the [`Debugger.IsAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property at the start of your `ToString` method and implement alternative behavior.

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
#IF (DEBUG)
        if ( Debugger.IsAttached )
        {
            return this.GetType().Name + ": " + this.Title; // or something else.
        }
#ENDIF
        // The rest of your ToString implementation
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

change the name of ToString() function to sth else

Comment: That will change the behavior of the program outside of the debugger.  He may well be relying on this implementation of `ToString` throughout his program.

Comment: @Servy: I can't understand! Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: He may have `Console.WriteLine(form)` somewhere, or using a logging framework that accepts objects of type `object` which then rely on using `ToString` to get the string representation of the object.  This would break any such code, but without generating compiler errors.

Comment: Oh! I hadn't noticed the word "override". Sorry!